# Find string then copy and paste in another worksheet for specific columns

Tags: excel, macros, vba

I am relatively new to VBA and am slowly learning.

I have a very basic macro that will look for the word `PASS` in column `C` on my first worksheet, and then copy the entire row to a secondary worksheet which is also called `PASS`.

I am trying to only copy and paste the data in that row from columns `A:E`. Below is my current code. I have tried adding `.range("A:E")`, but then it does nothing.

Any help on how to get this to only copy the information in columns `A-E` for that particular row would be greatly appreciated.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim C As Range

  If Intersect(Target, Me.Range("C:C")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
  For Each C In Intersect(Target, Me.Range("C:C")).Cells
    If C.Text = "PASS" Then
      C.EntireRow.Copy Worksheets("PASS").Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(1).EntireRow
    End If  
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to specify the row number as well as the column when referencing ranges. `range("A:E")` only specifies the columns. It needs to be something like `range("a54:e54").

Comment: @Scott Marcus - you can reference whole columns like that although it is not efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim C As Range

  If Intersect(Target, Me.Range("C:C")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
  For Each C In Intersect(Target, Me.Range("C:C")).Cells
    If C.Text = "PASS" Then
      cells(C.Row,1).resize(,5).Copy Worksheets("PASS").Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(1).EntireRow
    End If  
  Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I've adapted your code and changed the following:

- defined some `Range` variables to keep the code simpler
- if the change was in column C then the `Target` cell gives us the row
- find the target row on the `PASS` sheet by getting last row + 1
- define the data to be copied by using the row of `Target` but columns `A` to `E`
- get the first cell of the target range and then do the copy

Here's the code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim rngSource As Range
    Dim lngTargetRow As Long
    Dim rngTarget As Range

    'was change in column C ?
    If Intersect(Target, Me.Range("C:C")) Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'change was in column C - was PASS entered
    If Target.Text = "PASS" Then
        'get row to copy to on PASS sheet
        lngTargetRow = Worksheets("PASS").Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        'get source range
        Set rngSource = Me.Range("A" & Target.Row & ":E" & Target.Row)
        'set target range
        Set rngTarget = Worksheets("PASS").Cells(lngTargetRow, 1)
        'do the copy
        rngSource.Copy Destination:=rngTarget
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. This also works! I am going to go with the first answer from SJR because as a newbie, it makes more sense and I am able to follow the code through and understand. This is just a small part of my macro, so I want to keep it as basic as possible.